# How to extract JavaScript link from HTML page in Java?

Tags: java, javascript, html-parsing, hyperlink

I have HTML pages as String in Java and I need to extract the JavaScript links from it. Is there any good and easy to use library that I can use? I looked up [Cobra](http://lobobrowser.org/cobra.jsp) and [Neko](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/), but I don't think (maybe I'm wrong) that they have what I need, such as getting tag specific content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/).  It is an HTML parser that has a selector-DSL (Domain Specific Language) for finding elements of the dom.

For example, to find all `a` tags with an `href`, you would do this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com/").get();
Elements hrefAnchors = doc.select("a[href]");
```

If you already have the html downloaded as a `String`, you can use the `parse(String)` method:

```
String html = "<p>Welcome to <a href='http://www.google.com/'>Google</a>.</p>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
```

Comment: thankyou for your reply . I'll definitely look into it. But as i said above i already have parsed page as string.I dont need to make a new connection to get page . Will 'Jsoup' work in that case too ?